# run java server from python and wait until it is up

Tags: java, python, subprocess, grizzly

So I run java server from terminal calling it with:

`java =Xmx12G - jar jar.jar --build ../foo --inMemory`

then it takes some time for the server to step up, sometimes a minute sometime more.

I want to wait until it is up.

I used `subprocess.call()` but then it does not terminate, so it waits forever.
How can I wait until there is an output:

`16:53:28.315 INFO (GrizzlyServer.java:153) Grizzly server running.`

Comment: check if server has some healthcheck endpoint. Nowdays many frameworks provide such API out of box. Also you can just ping port that server running and wait for some response that != unavailable.

Comment: also its possible to use jmx but its I guess its pretty hard to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1.) subprocess.call() waits until the java server exits.
2.) When the parent (Python) process stops usually the child process gets killed.

In case you still need to make it via Python script, you could run the java server in a separate process group, so it's decoupled from the parent (Python process) - that just works on *nix OSes:

```
import os
import time
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(
    ['nohup', 'java', '=Xmx12G', '-jar', 'jar.jar', '--build', '../foo', '--inMemory']
    stdout=open('/tmp/logOut.log', 'w'),
    stderr=open('/tmp/logErr.log', 'w'),
    preexec_fn=os.setpgrp
)

while True:
    if 'Grizzly server running' in open('/tmp/logOut.log').read():
        break
    time.sleep(1)
```

Note: You need to pipe into files and read them in Python, if you would pipe into the Python script and the script exits the child process gets killed (no matter if the processes are decoupled)

Comment: looks nice. 
And this can be embedded in a routine, i.e. I run the server, wait until is up, and then call this server in one linear execution, right?

Comment: Probably, yes :)